# UIKIT Error String

Tags: xcode, debugging, crash-log

I am using Crashlytics in my application. Below is my crash log that I am having a hard time going through...

I get the error

> whoa! Too low of a row...! 24hrs 59mins is the max timer interval, for
>   now...

which is a UIKIT related error.

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

```
 ...
CoreFoundation  
__exceptionPreprocess + 162
1    libobjc.A.dylib    
objc_exception_throw + 32
2    CoreFoundation 
+[NSException raise:format:]
3    Foundation 
-[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 90
4    UIKit  
-[UIDatePickerView _updateRowInColumn:toValue:withRepeatingAmount:element:animated:] + 538
5    UIKit  
-[UIDatePickerView _loadDateAnimated:] + 264
6    UIKit  
-[UIDatePickerView _updateBitsForDate:forced:andReload:animateIfNeeded:] + 696
7    UIKit  
-[UIDatePickerView _setDate:animated:forced:] + 348
8    UIKit  
-[UIDatePickerView setDate:animated:] + 30
9    UIKit  
-[UIDatePicker setDate:] + 36
10   App ✭   EditAccountViewController.m line 571
-[EditAccountViewController textFieldDidBeginEditing:] + 571
11   UIKit  
-[UITextField _becomeFirstResponder] + 402
12   UIKit  
-[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 336
13   UIKit  
-[UITextInteractionAssistant setFirstResponderIfNecessary] + 174
14   UIKit  
-[UITextInteractionAssistant oneFingerTap:] + 1608
15   UIKit  
_UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 106
16   UIKit  
-[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:] + 304
17   UIKit  
___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke_0541 + 48
18   UIKit  
_UIGestureRecognizerApplyBlocksToArray + 176
19   UIKit  
_UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 898
20   UIKit  
_UIGestureRecognizerUpdateGesturesFromSendEvent + 28
21   UIKit  
-[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 774
22   UIKit  
-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 88
23   UIKit  
-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 356
24   UIKit  
_UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5826
25   GraphicsServices   
PurpleEventCallback + 882
26
...
CoreFoundation  
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 38
32   UIKit  
UIApplicationMain + 1080
33   App     main.m line 15
main + 15
34   App    
 start
```

The line that the app is telling me the crash is accuring on is as follow

```
_birthDatePicker.date = _birthDate;
```

Comment: I came up with exactly the same problem. When setting `0002-11-30 00:00:00 +0000` to DatePicker.date, the "Whoa!" just showed up. All I could do is forcefully setting this kind of date to something like `1900-11-30 00:00:00 +0000` to avoid crash.
Much appreciate if someone has any idea.

Comment: I emailed apple they said it was there fault and a bug in uikit... nothing we can do.

Comment: At least we know the reason now. My problem was due to storing a `0000-00-00 00:00:00 +0000`, a nil date, to core data and it seems the data base just automatically stores it as `0002-11-30 00:00:00 +0000`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was confirmed by apple as a bug on their part.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a crash reporter like TestFlight or Crittercism that lets you add event tracking to your crash reports - it's been super helpful in letting me reproduce a crash:

https://www.crittercism.com/developers/docs-optional#breadcrumb_trails